# On the p-th coefficients of the $\eta(\tau)\eta(23\tau)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

I am trying to prove the the well-known result:

$a_{p}=0$   if  $\left( \frac{p}{23}  \right)=-1$

$a_{p}=2 $ if  $\left( \frac{p}{23}  \right)=1$ and $p$ is represented by $x^2+xy+6y^2$

$a_{p}=-1 $ if  $\left( \frac{p}{23} \right)=1$ and $p$ is represented by $ 2x^2+xy+3y^2 $

where $a_{p}$ is the coefficient of $q^{p}$ in

$\eta(\tau)\eta(23\tau)=q\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-q^k)(1-q^{23k})
$

I know that $N_{p}(f)=a_{p}+1$ where $N_{p}$
is the number of roots of the polynomial $f(x)=x^3-x-1 \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$, but I am trying to compute $ a_{p}$ from the $q$-expansion.

Here is my attempt.

Using the Euler pentagonal number theorem, we have

$$\eta(\tau)\eta(23\tau)=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-q^k)(1-q^{23k})= $$
$$\sum_{x,y \in \mathbb{Z}} (-1)^{n+m} q^{(3n^2+n+69m^2+23m+2)/2}
=  $$ $$ \sum_{x,y \in \mathbb{Z}} (-1)^{n+m} q^{((6m+1)^2+23(6n+1)^2)/24}.
$$
It remains to determine when p is represented by the quadratic form  $Q(x,y)=x^2+23y^2$. We know that p must verify $ \left( \frac{p}{23}\right)=1$, but I could not go any further.

Comment: if you have an odd number $n$  with $n=u^2 + uv + 6 v^2,$  then $u^2 + uv = u(u+v)  $   must be odd, so both $u, u+v$ must be odd, finally $v$  is even. Let $v = 2 t$  Then $n = u^2 + 2ut + 24 t^2 = (u+t)^2 + 23 t^2.$  Any odd number, including odd primes, represented by $(1,1,6)$ is also represented by $(1,0,23).$  For $(2,1,3)$ same argument gives $(3,2,8).$  Finally, a prime is represented by, at most, two forms of a given discriminant. If two, these are some form $f$ and its "opposite."

Comment: @WillJagy but how (2,1,3) gives (3,2,8) will helpful we want (1,0,23)

Comment: You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs. This is particularly relevant for legibility if you mix fractions and exponents.